# Show image caption centered over image and center with css or jquery possible?

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to add a centered caption over an image, almost there. see:http://cssdesk.com/2wreQ
But I want and can't get the text paragraph (p.wp-caption-text to) be centered. Can't get it done and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to do it with css or jquery.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use margin-left:value;, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made it more complicated than it needs to be. And jQuery is not at all necessary.

[My suggestion in action.](http://cssdesk.com/jegSJ) I've removed the inline width on the `.wp-caption` element as that's not a great practice, and it complicates things. You shouldn't need any of the `z-index` values, and `position: absolute` was actually creating your problem since it didn't have a defined width. For the caption text to be centered on the image, the caption text element would need to own the full width of the image. You could accomplish this by simply adding `width: 140px;` to `.wp-caption-text` but then you'd end up with other problems down the line.

By removing `position: absolute;`, the paragraph goes back to using the full width available to it (after applying margin), and the `text-align: center;` property applied to `.wp-caption` does its job. The changes to margin and padding were primarily to simplify the CSS and make it easier to work with, but they should also fix some browser issues you likely would have run across later. I also applied some non-controversial formatting. I.e., I reordered the properties, removed duplicates, added spacing.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="attachment_24" class="wp-caption alignnone"><a href="http://zoekmachineoptimalisatielab.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Koala.jpg"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-24" title="Koala" src="http://zoekmachineoptimalisatielab.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Koala-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Koala caption</p></div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

CSS

```
#content .wp-caption {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 168px;
}
#content .wp-caption a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 9px;
}
#content .wp-caption-text {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CACACA;
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -12px 9px 0;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should this one

add one properties in your css

```
#content .wp-caption {
position:relative;
}
```

and  Replace to this css  `**#content .wp-caption p.wp-caption-text**`  into this

```
#content .wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
    bottom: 24px;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 9px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/seK84/

Answer (score 0):

I assume u have fixed width of 160px of attachment_24.
Add this to your css.

```
p.wp-caption-text{
    width:140px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping me in right direction..
This is what I had in mind: http://cssdesk.com/tVpxK and thanks to your help I got it working..